# SSH chmod doesn't work?

Tags: ssh

I have a problem with chmodden files in de Secure shell environment. I've selected a map structure and want to change the `/test/index.html` to chmod (000) Allready traced the file, and get this output back. Just started and don't know whats wrong about it? Who can help me out?

```
[admin@web test]# strace chmod 000 index.html 
execve("/bin/chmod", ["chmod", "000", "index.html"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1211000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f56302c0000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=28322, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 28322, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f56302b9000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\356\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1923352, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3750184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f562fd0e000
mprotect(0x7f562fe98000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f5630098000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18a000) = 0x7f5630098000
mmap(0x7f563009e000, 14632, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f563009e000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f56302b8000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f56302b7000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f56302b6000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f56302b7700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f5630098000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f56302c1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f56302b9000, 28322)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1211000
brk(0x1232000)                          = 0x1232000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99164480, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99164480, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f5629e7b000
close(3)                                = 0
umask(0)                                = 022
stat("index.html", {st_mode=S_IFREG, st_size=8747, ...}) = 0
fchmodat(AT_FDCWD, "index.html", 0)     = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: `fchmodat(AT_FDCWD, "index.html", 0)     = 0` According to your trace, the chmod operation is successful. Could you [edit] your question to demonstrate why you think it's failing?

Comment: thanks for you anwser, yes of cource. When i check it by SFTP the liberties did not changed. Chmod must work immediatly, right?   sidenote* its takes 30 seconds to show it on the SFTP side. Thank to Kenster for checking, my appreciation.